# How to pass entire json object as a value of one of the JSON key inside Object Repository Katalon studio API?

Tags: rest, katalon-studio

```
{
"id":"${id}",
  "personaForOrgTypeList": [{"id": "${id}","name1": "${name1}","alias":"${alias}"}]
}
```

Below is the katalon way of passing:

```
responseObj=WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('Object Repository/API/Organization/POST_for_organizationLevelWithValidPersonaNoParent',[('id'): id,personaForOrgTypeList':[('personaName'):personaName,('alias'):personaAlias,('id'):personaid]]))
```

The above expression is working fine for 'id' but not for 'personaForOrgTypeList'.
Looking forward to some help, it's really important.

How to pass the entire JSON object inside JsonArray inside the object repository?